# custom Flume interceptor: intercept() method called multiple times for the same Event

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

**TL;DR**

When a Flume source fails to push a transaction to the next channel in the pipeline, does it always keep event instances for the next try?

In general, is it safe to have a *stateful* Flume interceptor, where processing of events depends on previously processed events?

**Full problem description:**

I am considering the possibility of leveraging guarantees offered by Apache Kafka regarding the way topic partitions are distributed among consumers in a consumer group to perform streaming deduplication in an existing Flume-based log consolidation architecture.

Using the Kafka Source for Flume and custom routing to Kafka topic partitions, I can ensure that every event that should go to the same logical "deduplication queue" will be processed by a single Flume agent in the cluster (for as long as there are no agent stops/starts within the cluster). I have the following setup using a custom-made Flume interceptor:

[KafkaSource with deduplication interceptor]-->()MemoryChannel)-->[HDFSSink]

It seems that when the Flume Kafka source runner is unable to push a batch of events to the memory channel, the event instances that are part of the batch are passed again to my interceptor's `intercept()` method. In this case, it was easy to add a tag (in the form of a Flume event header) to processed events to distinguish actual duplicates from events in a failed batch that got re-processed.

However, I would like to know if there is any explicit guarantee that Event instances in failed transactions are kept for the next try or if there is the possibility that events are read again from the actual source (in this case, Kafka) and re-built from zero. In that case, my interceptor will consider those events to be duplicates and discard them, even though they were never delivered to the channel.

**EDIT**

This is how my interceptor distinguishes an Event instance that was already processed from a non-processed event:

```
public Event intercept(Event event) {
  Map<String,String> headers = event.getHeaders();
  // tagHeaderName is the name of the header used to tag events, never null
  if( !tagHeaderName.isEmpty() ) {
    // Don't look further if event was already processed...
    if( headers.get(tagHeaderName)!=null )
      return event;
    // Mark it as processed otherwise...
    else
      headers.put(tagHeaderName, "");
  }
  // Continue processing of event...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue:

When a sink write failed, Kafka Source still hold the data that has already been processed by interceptors. In next attempt, those data will send to interceptors, and get processed again and again. By reading the KafkaSource's code, I believe it's bug.

My interceptor will strip some information from origin message, and will modify the origin message. Due to this bug, the retry mechanism will never work as expected.

So far, The is no easy solution.

Comment: The fact that the same Kafka event is processed again by the interceptor when the transaction with the channel fails is not a problem in itself; after all, the event couldn't be delivered so a retry is expected. What I'm wondering is whether there is a guarantee that the same Event **instance** in the JVM, with whatever modifications the interceptor made, will be used again or if there is the possibility (or in my case, the *risk*) that the event will be read again from the Kafka topic it came from.

Comment: Note that if you just want to distinguish an event instance that was already processed from another in your interceptor's code, you can just add a *tag* header to your event and skip processing of events with this *tag* header.